# Using only a for styling links with CSS

Tags: css

When styling links with CSS, is there a reason why not only a is used? Like below:

```
a {
    color: red;
}
a:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

I usually always see it like this:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    color: red;
}
a: hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

Is the first alternative wrong in any way?

Best Regards
Lars

Comment: they are right and `:link` `:visited` `:active` are the pseudo classes and after these events happens the style is applied to a

Comment: refer this [anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Answer (score 0):

The first alternative is not wrong in anyway. It is just used to make the rule clear and easy to read css. It's just as a matter of style.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct and both are separate from each other due to the event.

If you use only `a` for styling `anchor` tag than it will only style the anchor tag when it is **not** `clicked` or `hovered`

These `Pseudo` classes are the states when the `anchor` tag is  clicked or hovered than the style is applied.